# Midi controllers/ more specifically, a monome--open ended question

Tags: techniques, war, strategy

Does anybody use midi controllers for sound design?

More specifically does anybody use a monome?

Comment: IF you stick to in the box techniques, people can translate your work better between sessions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your traditional sound design, but the guy over at [SeeYouInSleep](http://seeyouinsleep.com/blog/) uses one all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I use midi for standard stuff like filter sweeps and granulation control.  The monome is an interesting idea.  You could definitely use it to augment ambiences/drones in a more linear/musical kind of way and keep in time with the score (if there is one).

Answer (score -5):

monomes are for music and you should never use them or any other midi controllers in sound ediiting

Comment: there's a couple of broad statements for ya.  sounds like rules that are asking to be broken to me.  :)

Comment: lol kinda like saying celery is only for cooking and shouldn't be used for sound design!

Comment: You're playing devil's advocate, right?  Please tell me you're playing devil's advocate.

Comment: basically anything you use out of purpose is a step backwards in tech

Comment: @Jennifer, don't you think using things out of purpose one of the joys in sound design? Great fictions like Jurassic Park, Star Wars or Terminator seem to be based on that.